# sql procedure auto iincrement if exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
procedure [dbo].[InsertSortCode] ( 
    @Sortcode varchar(25)
    , @verbiage varchar(200) ) 
as 
    begin 
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT appmaster  on

    insert into AppMaster(MainID,SortCode) values ( 
        (select MAX(mainid) 
         from AppMaster) + 1, @Sortcode )

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT appmaster  off 

    insert into Verbiage(MenueID,verbiage) values ( 
        (select MAX(mainid) 
         from AppMaster), @verbiage )
```

the above is my stored procedure it is working perfectly fine but there is an error if there is no data in the database 
the problem is with max function ,if the is no data in database 
 it cannot max out the id it works only if there is already some data
 with its id in that databse

need to figure out how to use the exist statement on this SP so that it can work with both empty table and filled table

Comment: Add case that checks when null then 1

Comment: You *could* just use `ISNULL((SELECT MAX(mainid) FROM AppMaster), 0) + 1` to get your "identity" value. It really begs the question what is the point though? Why have an identity column then set the number manually? If you care about the value of an identity column there is a pretty good chance you are not using it correctly.

Comment: For more about identity read - [Bad habits to kick : making assumptions about IDENTITY](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-making-assumptions-about-identity) - Also, regardless of your reasons for forcing the identity in the first insert, you should **definitely** be using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` for your second insert, doing another `select max` is not guaranteed to use the same value as the first insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following query:-

```
insert into AppMaster(MainID,SortCode) values ( 
(select ISNULL(MAX(mainid),0) 
from AppMaster) + 1, @Sortcode )
```

So if MAX(mainid) is null it will return as 0 and add 1 to that.

Comment: thanks bro this is my first day on stack over flow and you made my day  .the logic u gave works works absolutely fine for an empty table and again Thank you